# Custom domains for one site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a php web application on Apache that supports multiple users identified by dist_id in the query string. So https://main.com/login?dist_id=21 shows a differently styled page from https://main.com/login?dist_id=26

What I want to do is register a domain name for each user and keep the URLs clean so that https://brandx.com/login invisibly points to https://main.com/login?dist_id=21. After the login I don't need dist_id anymore but I want to keep the user's domain so that https://brandx.com/products?show=1 etc. still works.

Is this possible and what's the best way to do it (mod_write, DNS, in PHP)?

Note I already have a rewrite rule to add index.php which is the entry point for all requests.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I think I've gotten close with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dist_id=26 [QSA,L]
```

After logging in this works: https://brandx.com/categories but this gives a 404 error: https://brandx.com/categories?parent_id=12329

Comment: I don't know how to fix this but may I ask why you're doing it like this? Isn't it far easier to just setup apache for multiple domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably all of these "sites" would share an identical URL structures (minus query parameters)? In that case, it'd probably be simplest to set up a definition for your `main.com` site, and then add all of your `brandx.com` domains as aliases, e.g.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
   ServerName main.com
   ServerAlias brandx.com brandy.com brandz.com etc...
</virtualhost>
```

Then you use mod_rewrite to test the HTTP 'Host:` header to see which domain the users are hitting, and re-write as appropriate.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking but I'm a idiot when it comes to mod_write. What would the host test and rewrite rule look like?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond  shows the vars you can test, including http_host